# Migration of old meta-questions to meta

Tags: discussion, migration, meta

Should we migrate old [meta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) and [site-policy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-policy) questions (with some exceptions) from the main site to the meta site, or just leave them as they are? What are the pros and cons to each approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently four [site-policy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-policy) questions. IMO three of them are about Jewish life and learning; only ["Anonymity on mi.yodeya.com"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/684) is not. I say keep the three on main and detag them, and move the other hither.

As to [meta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta), again, some are and some are not J.l.a.l.-related. In particular, IMO, ["Can I ask questions about the talmud and Chumash?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6846) and ["Should I populate this site with questions?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1486) are not, while ["Mi.Yodeya. com for Children"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1004) and ["False portrayal on an anonymous Q&A site"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6534) are. Keep the latter on main (and perhaps detag them?), while moving and detagging the former.

Comment: OK, I've migrated and re-tagged (with, at least pre-migration) the ones that seemed to belong only on meta. I may or may not re-tag the others, which will remain on the main site.